# To print PASS/FAIL status in excel , after coded UI tests

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am using Coded UI for testing.
I have a set of 5 fields to be validated in one page.
I have added assert and record methods and all that is working fine.
Is it possible to import an excel file with field level validations and mark Pass/Fail status in that excel sheet through Coded UI?
Like, the test result should be printed in the last column of the excel sheet across each of the fields.
Is that possible?

Comment: Any more specific questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

Here's how to read from excel:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624082.aspx

And here are some links to help write to excel:
[Writing to an existing Excel File using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16722339/writing-to-an-existing-excel-file-using-c-sharp)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264733.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/613782/Read-and-Write-Excel-File-Dynamically